# Arrive Steering Behaviour velocity not decreasing properly

Tags: movement, steering-behaviors

I'm trying to implement the Arrive Steering Behaviour with acceleration from AI For Games 3rd edition by Ian Millington (Algorithm on Page 63)

```
function getSteering() -> SteeringOutput:
    result = new SteeringOutput()

    direction = target.position - character.position
    distance = direction.length()
    
    if distance < targetRadius:
        return null

    if distance > slowRadius:
       targetSpeed = maxSpeed
    else:
       targetSpeed = maxSpeed * distance / slowRadius

    targetVelocity = direction
    targetVelocity.normalize()
    targetVelocity *= targetSpeed

    result.linear = targetVelocity - character.velocity
    result.linear /= timeToTarget

    if result.linear.length() > maxAcceleration:
        result.linear.normalize()
        result.linear *= maxAcceleration
 
    result.angular = 0
    return result
```

My implementation in C++ is as follows:

```
SteeringOutput result{};

Vector2D direction  = target->position - character->position;
float distance      = direction.getLength();

if (distance < targetRadius)
    return result;

float targetSpeed{};

if (distance > slowRadius)
    targetSpeed = maxSpeed;
else
    targetSpeed = maxSpeed * distance / slowRadius;

Vector2D targetVelocity = direction;
targetVelocity.normalise();
targetVelocity          *= targetSpeed;

result.linear = targetVelocity - character->velocity;
result.linear /= timeToTarget;

if (result.linear.getLength() > maxAcceleration)
{
    result.linear.normalise();
    result.linear *= maxAcceleration;
}

result.angular = 0;

return result;
```

The update rule for the characters is:

```
character.position.x    += character.velocity.x * time;
character.position.y    += character.velocity.y * time;

character.orientation   += character.rotation * time;

character.velocity += steering.linear  * time;
character.rotation += steering.angular * time;

if (character.velocity.getLength() > maxSpeed)
{
    character.velocity.normalise();
    character.velocity *= maxSpeed;
}
```

The algorithm works until the target is supposed to arrive within the target radius.
Once the distance between target and character is less than the target radius the velocity of the character should be zero. However, the character arrives within target radius with non-zero velocity and continues to move until it reaches the target and then oscillates like the Seek Behaviour.

I've tried adjusting the values to change the behaviour but every time the character arrives with some non-zero velocity.
I've also tried to calculate the distance between the character and one point on the circle in the target radius, and that does seem to work better, but it's still non-zero.

Some other approaches involve setting the velocity to zero manually once the character is inside the targetRadius, but I don't think it's supposed to be fixed that way.

Do you have any ideas what might be wrong ? Is there something missing from the algorithm ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is `timeToTarget` calculated? Is it `0` upon arrival? If so are you getting a division by zero on this line `result.linear /= timeToTarget;`?

Comment: `timeToTarget` is specified. The author suggests setting it to 0.1. I also tried setting it to 0.01, 0.05 and 0.001 but it didn't change the situation much.

Comment: So... I'm not familiar with the implementation you're reference. I've used this one before myself https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-steering-behaviors-flee-and-arrival--gamedev-1303 to good outcome. It works by effectively applying a damping force that peaks on arrival. It may or may not be of use to you.

Comment: I've modified the steering behaviour to be the same as in the link you provided but it still overshoots the target... Here's a visual representation [link](https://gifyu.com/image/ShQMu). Here's the new [code](https://gifyu.com/image/ShQMJ) maybe you have some ideas. Thank you for your input so far.